# Running a python script on a ubuntu server and connect to server and interact with script

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh

I am not sure how to approach this project but my goal is to have a python script constantly running on a ubuntu server in the cloud then being able to connect to my server via ssh and then being able to interact with the python script that is running but i am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `screen` or `tmux` after establishing ssh connection.

Install tmux (it is usually installed by default) just in case:

```
sudo apt install tmux
```

them run `tmux`

Inside the tmux session, you can run the script and interact with it.
Whenever you got disconnected; the script will continue working.

After re-establishing ssh connection you can do `tmux at` and continue working with your script and check its log.
For more information on tmux check out [this link](https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/).